# Can I make require() to fetch me the same object instance every time I call it?

Tags: node.js

I want to create a socket.IO object in my app, and I want to make it accessible from everywhere in my application, without using GLOBALS or hacks, and also make sure that only one instance is loaded at all times.

After some thought, I came up with this module

```
var io = null;

// This module is a siglenton. It initializes itself
// the first time require() calls it and all the 
// next times  it simply returns the object that was 
// initally created
module.exports = function(server){
// If io is not initialized, initialize it before returning

if(!io)
{
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
      socket.on('message', function (data) {
          //Do stuff
      });
    });
}

return io;
}
```

It seems to work well in theory, but in practice it keeps generating new objects every time

```
var http_server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});


var a = require('my_io')(http_server);
var b = require('my_io')();
console.log(a === b); //Echoes false
```

Am I missing something here? How am I supposed to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I finally did

Changed my module to this:

```
var IO_Object = function(){

  this.io = null;

  this.init = function(server){
    this.io = require('socket.io').listen(server);      

    this.io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.on('sync_attempt', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
  };
};


module.exports = new IO_Object();
```

I do this at my app.js to initialize the object

```
var my_IO = require('my_io');
my_IO.init(http_server);
```

And after that I `require('my_io')` everywhere in my app, in order to get the initial instance. Works perfectly!